# How to mock function returning AnyVal with Mockito in Scala / Specs2?

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I would like to stub a function returning AnyVal using Mockito in Scala (Specs2 to be precise), but it doesn't seam to work:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.mock._

case class V(s: String) extends AnyVal

class A {
  def f: V = new V("Hello")
}

class Sample extends Specification with Mockito {
    "Mockito" should {
        "mock A" in {
            val a = mock[A]
            a.f returns new V("hoge")
            a.f match {
                case V("hoge") => success
                case _ => failure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with:

```
V cannot be returned by f()
f() should return String
```

I found kind of workaround (based on which I provided above snippet) using marker interface/trait:
https://gist.github.com/mtgto/9251779

but this is not any solution for me, hence it changes returned type (because of mocking/test library issue).

Anyone has seen this before and knows how to stub such function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found one way of stubbing this function - using original Mockito's doReturn with underlying AnyVal's type (String in this case) instead of AnyVal itself, so:

```
org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn("hoge").when(a).f
```

instead of:

```
a.f returns new V("hoge")
```

Comment: I've tried a few things and I don't think there's a better way that what you are doing. `doReturn` is not typechecked whereas `returns` is  so this is why this is working. One more issue in the Scala/Java interop. issues book I guess.